# Adding string inside the brackets using javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

`"AddMoreRowsWithNo('SnapIII_btnEquipmentAddMore', 'SnapIII_TBLAdditionalEquipment', 'SnapIII_trAdditionalEquipment', 'SnapIII_tdEquipmentNo')"`

I need to add value before closing bracket inside the string.
for example,

`AddMoreRowsWithNo('SnapIII_btnEquipmentAddMore', 'SnapIII_TBLAdditionalEquipment', 'SnapIII_trAdditionalEquipment', 'SnapIII_tdEquipmentNo', valCount);`

Comment: did you google? it is very common problem and its solution.

Comment: actually the above string is stored inside the variable. For example,        var addbtnattr = $("#SnapIII_btnEquipmentAddMore")[0];                        var nodeval = addbtnattr.attributes[2].nodeValue;  The above string is stored inside the variable nodeVal. so it is difficult to add one more value inside the string which is stored in nodeVal variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is function with regexp and replace function, in first time will pass name of func as variable, in second time - your func params

```
 function addParams(funcStr, paramsArrayToAdd){
   var isFirstCall = false;
   return funcStr.replace(/[^\)\(]+/g,function(str){
      if(!isFirstCall){
        isFirstCall = true;
        return str;
      }else{
        return str.length > 0 ? str + "," + paramsArrayToAdd.join(",") : paramsArrayToAdd.join(",");
      }
   });
}
```

Example of use

```
    var str = addParams("AddMoreRowsWithNo('SnapIII_btnEquipmentAddMore', 'SnapIII_TBLAdditionalEquipment', 'SnapIII_trAdditionalEquipment', 'SnapIII_tdEquipmentNo')",["'param1'","'param2'"])
    console.log(str);//AddMoreRowsWithNo('SnapIII_btnEquipmentAddMore', 'SnapIII_TBLAdditionalEquipment', 'SnapIII_trAdditionalEquipment', 'SnapIII_tdEquipmentNo','param1','param2')
```